# Unable to use Spring and Spring Security jars from CATALINA_HOME/lib folder

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, jar, spring-security

I'm developing a java web application, which is deployed on `tomcat 7`.
I'm using `Maven, Spring, spring security 3.0.5.RELEASE and JSF` in this application.

I want to place spring and jsf jar files in `CATALINA_HOME/lib`, because I'm using them in other application too. Now I have most of those jars in my war file.

The steps I'm doing for separating jars from war file are following:

1. adding `<scope>provided</scope> tag` dependency in `pom.xml`
2. placing the jar file in `CATALINA_HOME/lib`

When I did these steps for JSF jars, everything worked correctly.

**But when I did the same for spring and spring security jars app didn't start and threw error.**

For example: If I add `<scope>provided</scope>` tag to the following dependency my app stops working and throws `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource` exception:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

please see **full stack trace** in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PNV5f/) and **pom.xml** in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mBTdZ/)

How can I make my webapp work with spring jars places in CATALINA_HOME/lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to put application jars in your tomcat lib directory. Keep them all in your war so that they are restricted to that application. You will find this exception repeated many times if you search.

Another common mistake people make (and which isn't obvious) is that the identity of a class from the JVM's perspective is both the class name *and the identity of the classloader which loaded it*. So if two classloaders load the same class, you cannot cast an instance of one to the other.

Classloaders are often confusing and you're best to stick to the standard approach people use. Put all your application jars in your `WEB-INF/lib` so they are isolated from other applications and make sure you don't have any duplicate jars around in common lib directories. Also check your application to make sure you only have one version of each jar.

The only thing you should usually need to mark as `provided` in a web application is the `servlet-api` jar.

Answer (score 1):

You ran into a classloader issue.

Some of your classes need some others that are loaded with another classloader.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html for more information.

It may seem a good idea to try to put Spring out of your war (to share it, or to minimize the size of the war) but it leads to trouble.

Even if you manage to make it work, you will end up with a mess with the logging APIs...